# React / React Router - Treat <a> tags like <Link> tags

Tags: html, reactjs

I am passing pre-compiled HTML to my React component through props. The original data looks something like this.

```
let pageData = [
   title  : 'About',
   content: '<p>Hello <strong> World!</p><a href="/contact">Contact</a>'
]
```

Then in the component using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method because I'm not sure if there is anything else to use.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class PostText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.content}}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But my question is, how can I convert the `<a href="/contact">Contact</a>` tag to `<Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>`.

Even if I don't change the mark up, is there a way to to do something like, "when I click an `<a>` tag, treat is as `<Link>` tag".

Comment: Can't you directly pass `<Link>...</Link>`? What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/393#issuecomment-193571968) seem helpful?

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do something like this, intercepting links click events inside you div and navigating with router:

```
<div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.content}}
    onClick={event => this.navigate(event)}
  />
</div>
```

and then:

```
navigate (event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
    this.props.router.push(event.target.getAttribute('href'))
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that if your link elements have any nested elements, you need to use something like `event.target.closest('a')` to get the enclosing anchor.

Comment: @TrevorRobinson should not be necessary, as event.target is supposed to be `a` already.

Comment: My firsthand testing in a browser (Chrome) and the [DOM spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click) don't support your opinion. `event.target` is the [topmost event target](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#topmost-event-target), not the element associated with the handler. Maybe you're thinking of [`event.currentTarget`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#current-event-target).

Comment: @TrevorRobinson Oh, inner elements inside, `a`. For that you indeed need to take extra check with either closest or while loop.